# Fuse tap direction. Please help me understand which way is correct

Tags: automotive, fuses

I have a car fuse tap and was wondering if it is directional and why?
Please help me understand from bottom 2 variations which direction should I install it and why.

Thank you!

**Fuse Tap:** 
[image: Fuse Tap]
[image: Fuse Tap Usage Variations]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the light bulb goes, it is protected by the 30 A fuse in both configurations.

But, in case 2, the current for the red +12 V path and the light bulb flows through the 30 A fuse.  This may (or may not) cause the 30 A fuse to blow.  It all depends on the current the light bulb and the red +12 V path pull.

In case 1, the red +12 V current only flows through the 5 A fuse.

Also in case 2, if the 30 A fuse blows, you will lose both the light bulb and whatever is connected to the red +12 V path.  This may not be desirable.

Therefore I think configuration 1 is what you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Figure 1 is the correct arrangement.

The lower left "+12V" is the power source, while the upper right "+12V" terminal is the output to another load.

The 30 Amp fuse would provide power to the original load while the 5 Amp fuse provides power to the new load.